# Convert C++ Program with std::cout to NCurses / CDK

Tags: c++, cout, ncurses

I have a large program written in C++ that uses `std::cout` in a lot of places. I am building an NCurses version and `std::cout` destroys that interface.

Is there a way to reroute the console output from `std::cout` to something like [cdk_swindow](http://invisible-island.net/cdk/manpage/cdk_swindow.3.html)?

Comment: I am using the buffer class from [this answer][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18981688/693279

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to override the << operator. This way in your case you can use cdk_swindow

Answer (score 0):

I rememeber `std:cout` didn't work in ncurses framwork and i use `printf function`, you use a `regex` with `sed` and convert you std:cout to `printf function`.But it's hard code and dirty anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at the CDK examples (http://invisible-island.net/cdk/)

Since CDK 'takes over' an Xterm, you probably will want to create a wrapper function that spews the text that used to go to the console, into something like CDKVIEWER.